# match(join) two dataframe using regular expression in r

Tags: r

I need to match two dataframe, but there id is not exactly the same. id2 maybe longer, but contains all characters in id1. how do I left_join two table without losing information. for example **182219556** and 485**182219556** are deemed as the same.

```
library(tidyverse)
data1 <- tibble(id = c(175642619,172881781,182219556,41925997,201404118),
            case_id=c(2746306,2746823,2749855,2749933,2750222))

data2 <- tibble(id = c(175642619,172881781568,485182219556,41925997,201404118),
            case_id2=c(2746306,2746823,2749855,2749933,2750222))

left_join(data1, data2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `fuzzyjoin` library. There is `stringdist_left_join` which is a left join based on a distance between two strings. In your case, I put `max_dist` equal to 3. Meaning that, two strings are deemed as same allowing maximum distance up to 3 characters between two strings which is your case.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
stringdist_left_join(data1, data2, by ="id", max_dist = 3)

#       id.x  case_id         id.y  case_id2
#1 175642619  2746306    175642619   2746306
#2 172881781  2746823 172881781568   2746823
#3 182219556  2749855 485182219556   2749855
#4 41925997   2749933     41925997   2749933
#5 201404118  2750222    201404118   2750222
```

Comment: what if the length of id2 is two times of id1?

Comment: In that case, you increase the `max_dist`. In your case, it shall be difference between the two strings. Lets say length of id1 is 5 and length of id2 is 8. So, `max_dist` for this example would be 5.

Comment: I meant length of id2 is 10 in my comment.

Comment: Build test data and test different value of max_dist in fuzzyjoin.

Comment: **6143037** and 167911374**6143037** ,   **177439699** and **177439699**26239287, I find two real case from my data. Originally it's two different product, then these two product been merged in to one product, so they just concatenate two _id_s.

Comment: As I said, build test data of all of your possible product id cases and then try different value for max_dist. Choose max_dist value that gives the result you are expecting. It is a trial and error procedure.